# Change return value of a boolean function in arm library

Tags: radare2

I have an android library (**arm cpu**) that have a function named **GetEisLinkWithDfr()** that have a single line that returns boolean value of "**true**", and I want it to return a value of "**false**".

I included isAWBEnabled() witch returns boolean value of "**true**" too, and isFlashAWBv2Enabled() witch returns boolean value of "**false**" as a show case.

I have attached the output when I run **iE** command and **izz** command in **radare2**.

nth   paddr      vaddr      len size section type    string

―――――――――――――――――――――――――

3462 0x000d45a4 0x000d85a4 GLOBAL FUNC   4         GetEisLinkWithDfr()

3461 0x000d45a4 0x000d85a4 GLOBAL FUNC   4         int isAWBEnabled<(NSIspTuning::ESensorDev_T)2>()

883  0x000d45a8 0x000d85a8 GLOBAL FUNC   4         isFlashAWBv2Enabled()

nth   paddr      vaddr      len size section                type    string

――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

6158  0x0007a4c1 0x0007e4c1 22  23   .dynstr                ascii   _Z17GetEisLinkWithDfrv

105   0x00019951 0x0001d951 52  53   .dynstr                ascii   _Z12isAWBEnabledILN11NSIspTuning12ESensorDev_TE2EEiv

141   0x00019f6f 0x0001df6f 24  25   .dynstr                ascii   _Z19isFlashAWBv2Enabledv